# Picture box doesn't show .gif format image animation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have developed one MenuForm one ParentForm and LoadingForm.When MenuForm button click to enter ParentForm If there have heavy process it shows LoadingForm before the process start and closed when process End.

I did everything and working fine except .gif format loading image animation is not working.I don't want to use any image animator class.Now My question is How can i load this .gif format image with animation in picturebox?

Code Snippet has given bellow;

As well as i belief if i get the answer this code snippet helps lot of developer to make simple loading screen using winform rather than using thread and asynchronous way.

```
' MENU FORM 

Public Class frmMenu
  Public Property FromForm As Form
    Private Sub btnMdr2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles _
       btnMdr2.Click

         FromForm = Me
         Dim mdr2Form As New ParentForm
         mdr2Form.Show()

    End Sub
End Class

'PARENT FORM

Public Class ParentForm
    Public Property FromForm As Form
  Public Sub MachineDailyReportForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)_ 
    Handles MyBase.Load

       FromForm = Me
      'Show loading screen 
       Dim loadingForm As New LoadingForm(FromForm)
       loadingForm.Show()

       'Use For loop to delay the process(add data in list) and to see 
       'loading screen 
         For i As Long = 0 To 1000000000
           If i = 1000000000 Then
              Exit For
           Else
              Continue For
           End If
         Next

        Dim list As New List(Of String)
        machineList.Items.Add("Wheel")
        machineList.Items.Add("Range")
        machineList.Items.Add("Gear")

       'Close loading screen 
       loadingForm.CloseLoadingDialog()
   End Sub
End Class

'LOADING FORM

Public Class LoadingForm
   Public Property FromForm As Form
   Public Sub New(ByVal FromForm As Form)
      InitializeComponent()
      Me.FromForm = FromForm
   End Sub
   Public Sub SplashScreen_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
       PictureBoxGif.Image = My.Resources.loading
       Show()
       Refresh()
   End Sub
   Public Sub CloseLoadingDialog()
      Me.Close()
      Me.Dispose()
   End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

I am using this loading.gif image it display in picture box but without spin.

Comment: A gif cannot animate when your code hangs the UI thread, that "heavy process" needs to run on a worker thread.  Use BackgroundWorker or Task.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are doing on the UI thread.  If you're doing anything at all then the then the UI thread is busy and cannot animate the `Image` in the `PictureBox`. Whatever you're doing, you need to do it asynchronously.

Comment: @jmcilhinney :Thanks for your answer.I knew that normally there have two approach for loading screen in winform application 1. Use background worker. 2. Use a control which work asynchronously.
But would like to make sure if there have any other way to fire gif image using Show method.By the way Thanks again and Thanks  to HansPassant for your reply.